# unable to join markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I require my plot - actually 4 plots in one - to show markers and a line joining the markers.

I am familiar with the command to achieve this - here are 2 of the plots

```
for i in range(30):
    plt.plot(x2[i+0],y2[i+0],'go-',label='HAlpha'if i == 0 else "") 


for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x3[i+0],y3[i+0],linestyle ='-' ,label='length 1 Re'if i == 0 else "",markersize=5,color='b',marker='^')
```

However in the uploaded plot nothing I have tried works to join the markers. In searching this question I read having a nan value or zero value can upset the joined markers but I tried removing the x=0 point  without success.

galaxyCOG.png

[image]

many thanks

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put the plot command inside the loop, you are creating a new line for each data point instead of the series. Since a line plot of only a singe data point cannot have any connections, you get only the markers. Try taking the plot command out of the loop (this will simplify your labeling as well).

```
for i in range(30):
    plt.plot(x2[i+0],y2[i+0],'go-',label='HAlpha'if i == 0 else "")
```

to

```
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'go-', label='HAlpha')
```